# How to add a space before the first letter of continuous uppercase letters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to add a space before the first letter of continuous uppercase letters in Python?

For example, if a string is "ABCDEzyxFGwvuHts", it should be split as:
" ABCDExyz FGwvu Hts"

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following simple solution with [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re

s = "ABCDEzyxFGwvuHts"
result = re.sub(r'([A-Z]+[^A-Z]+)', r' \1', s)

print result
```

The output:

```
 ABCDEzyx FGwvu Hts
```

Comment: This solution adds an extra space at the beginning. Remove that space and the output will be correct.

Comment: @HaiVu, look at the OP's output `" ABCDExyz FGwvu Hts"`. It has that space at the beginning

Comment: My bad. I must have been seeing things.